# Why would Umbraco serve an incorrect homepage?

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, umbraco

I recently inherited a system using the Umbraco CMS. The initial setup is a bit odd in that every node is a root node; there's no tree structure. Before today everything was functioning as expected. Navigating to www.mysite.com would display www.mysite.com/home, but there's never been any apparent redirect.

We started seeing some odd behavior today. Navigating to www.mysite.com now displays either www.mysite.com/home or www.mysite.com/someotherpage. It's always the same secondary page, but which one is served up seems to be random. You can hit f5 10 times and you'll get each one roughly half the time. Anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're seeing is that Umbraco is picking a node to show by random, due to you not having assigned a hostname to a specific node - and having multiple root nodes. I believe this can happen when the xml cache gets regenerated and the order of the generated xml changes a bit. To be sure you should either group all your pages under a single root node (like a folder called website) and then on that use a [umbracoInternalRedirectId](https://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbraco-best-practices/umbracointernalredirectid/) property to choose which node should be shown as the default page - or you should be able to assign a hostname to a specific node and have it pick that.

Comment: It does however sound a bit weird that it would change on just refreshes since this wouldn't regenerate the cached xml. Maybe there's variance in what element comes first on the query since all the root nodes will basically be equally "right" as a possible root node due to all of them being at the same level in the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Eache node has a Sort order, sometimes it happens that there are two identical. If there are no hostnames set on a node the first is your home.

So check the sort order and re-sorting.

Else set a dummy host on the not as home wanted node and or the hostname's on the home node (but the Link to document will then show the dummy host in the CMS where this is set, so if it is not necessary do not use a dummy host)

Other thing to check, In IIS check the Application pool, Advanced Settings, Maximum Worker Processes set it to 1 to ensure there is only 1 worker which should give every time the same response.